# Boon JsonFactory unable to parse list of list

Tags: java, json, boon

I am trying to parse a list of list attribute in my class using boon jsonfactory but the output is an empty list.

```
class Test {
    List<List<String>> id;

    public List<List<String>> getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(List<List<String>> id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id.toString();
    }
}


String myinput = "{ \"id\": [[\"INPUTID\"]]}";

Test receivedAdLogObj =  JsonFactory.create().fromJson(myinput, Test.class);

System.out.println(receivedAdLogObj.toString());
```

The output of the above program is [ ]

How can I parse the list of list of string in a json ??

Comment: You can't deserialize directly to a generic type because of type erasure. I'm not familiar with Boon, but I'm sure they have a workaround for generic types.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a few quick tests, this seems to be a limitation of the Boon JSON library. It seems to handle fields with one level of generics fine (i.e. `List<String>`), but it doesn't seem to like more nested structures like your `List<List<String>>`.

Using Gson or Jackson, your example works just fine:

```
System.out.println(new Gson().fromJson(myinput, Test.class));

System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().readValue(myinput, Test.class));
```

Both print the expected output:

```
[[INPUTID]]
```

Therefore I would maybe suggest looking at migrating to one of those two libraries if possible.

Comment: @andersschuller...yes you are correct. This is a limitation, hence I have changed my field to be of type List<String>.